# check if a function is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{C} → \mathbb{C}$ be defined as

$$f(z)= \begin{cases}\frac{x^3y(y − ix)}{x^6 +y^2}&\text{ if }z = x + iy= 0\\ 0 &\text{ if }z=x+iy=0\end{cases}$$

And holomorph at $z = 0$

I tried to apply the definition of holomorphic application, which is as follows:

$\displaystyle \lim_{(a, b) \to (0,0)} \frac{f (z_0 + h) - f (z_0)}{ h}$

Defining:

$f(x, y) = (xy^2 /x^4 -1, -x^2 y / x^4 -1)$

$f(x + a, y + b) = ((x + a) (y + b)^2 / (x + a)^4 -1, - (x + a)^2. (y + b) / (x + a)^4 -1)$

$f (z_0) = f (x, y) = (xy^2 / x^4 -1, -x^2 y / x^4 -1)$

$ h = (a, b)$

My question is how to solve this limit ...

My question is to define the limit of homologous functions or Verify if it is differentiable from a real point of view and use the cauchy rieman equations.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $f=u + iv$, so $u=\frac{xy^2}{x^4-1}$ and $v=\frac{-x^2y}{x^4-1}$.

calculating the partial derivatives we have:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{y^2(x^4-1)-xy^2(4x^3)}{(x^4-1)^2}$$

And

$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}= \frac{-2xy(x^4-1)-(-x^2y)(4x^3)}{(x^4-1)^2}$$

as the first equation is already different, it follows that f is not holomofa at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Write $f = u + iv$ and check that the Cauchy Riemann equations hold.

Comment: in your opinion it will not be holomorphic ??

Comment: I'm not sure.  Just do the calculation and you will find out.

Comment: It would be what the larrissa did, but if we apply the point $(0,0)$ both derivatives cancel each other out, don't you think?